# How to convert exFAT to FAT32? 

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, fat32, exfat

How to convert an exFAT-formatted USB flash drive to FAT32?

Comment: I think a better question is why would you want to do this? It's like wanting to install Windows 98 when you are running Windows XP.

Comment: Someone might want to do this if you have an existing USB with data to use on an older device that doesn't support exFat

Answer (score 14):

For more detailed information on exFAT there is a paper:
[Reverse Engineering the Microsoft exFAT File System](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/forensics/reverse-engineering-microsoft-exfat-file-system_33274) (86-page PDF)
in the SANS reading room.

Basically, there is no "convert" function between exFAT and other formats. You can't convert to exFAT, and you can't convert exFAT to FAT. Only conversions to NTFS are supported.

In your case, you need to copy all your files to a backup drive, reformat the USB device, and then copy the files back. But keep in mind that if you have files > 4 GB, they won't copy onto the FAT32 device because FAT32 does not support it.

Answer (score -2):

None of these tools worked for me including the Windows 7 Computer Management Storage utility.

Mac OS users can use `Disk Utility` to complete this process without any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score -3):

The fat32format [utility](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/index.htm?fat32format.htm) should do the trick.

It's a [GUI formatter](http://www.ridgecrop.demon.co.uk/guiformat.htm) for Windows users.

[image]

Comment: The links for the utility do not mention exFAT format handling. Is this a correct answer?

Comment: Conversion implies data retention.  This utility simply formats to FAT32, which will wipe data.