# Can I convert a partition from FAT to exFAT without losing data?

Tags: formatting, fat32, exfat

Is it possible to convert a partition from FAT to exFAT without having to transfer all the data off it and on it again?

Linux tools would be the best, but Windows ones are fine too.

Comment: Maybe you can find some inspiration here: http://superuser.com/questions/142140/how-to-convert-exfat-to-fat32 although that question is about the "reverse" conversion.