# Is there a way to convert FAT32 to exFAT without data loss?

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive, fat32, exfat, filesystem-conversion

Windows' [convert](https://ss64.com/nt/convert.html) command is able to convert FAT filesystems to NTFS non-destructively. Similarly, [fstransform](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform) is a Linux utility that is capable of doing this - calling it an "in-place" filesystem conversion - from and to a few more file systems, including NTFS and Ext3.

Is there something equivalent that will allow me to convert a FAT32 USB flash drive to exFAT?

Comment: Existing answer to this question, https://superuser.com/questions/142140/how-to-convert-exfat-to-fat32, indicates that it’s not possible to convert without data loss.